# numpy: applying scalar function to corresponding elements of different matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have the 4 following matrices:

```
w = [[w1, w2, w3, w4], [w5, w6, w7, w8], ...]
x = [[x1, x2, x3, x4], [x5, x6, x7, x8], ...]
y = [[y1, y2, y3, x4], [y5, y6, y7, y8], ...]
z = [[z1, z2, z3, x4], [z5, z6, z7, z8], ...]
```

These are of the shape (n,m). I want to apply a scalar function f to the corresponding elements of each matrix, such that the resultant matrix res is n by m as well, and the i-th, j-th element of res is the result of `func([[w[i,j], x[i,j]], [[y[i,j], z[i,j]])`

Obviously I can try looping through each element, but is there a vectorised/numpy implementation to this?

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe merging `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z` into some `N x M x 4` matrix and applying `numpy.ix`... Too tired right now to come up with the exact details. Although it might be slow... Something to consider.

Comment: For completely general f(w,x,y,z) I don't think there is a way to do this more efficiently than a for loop. Can you provide some details of what f does?

Answer (score 1):

make a generalised function of w, x, y, z to apply it elementwise in a vectorised way: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: This will work, but it won't generally be faster than a for loop